# Absolute value of the characters of elements of the center of a group

Tags: representation-theory

This question is Question 3.2 of Linear Representation of Finite Groups by Serre.

Let $\rho$ be an irreducible representation of $G$ of degree $n$ and character $\chi$; let
$C=C(G)$ be the center of $G$.

Show that $\rho_s$ is homothety for each $s \in C$. Deduce from this that $|\chi(s)|=n$ for all $s \in C$.

$st=ts$ and so $\rho_s \rho_t=\rho_t \rho_s$ for each $s \in C$ and all $t \in G$. Therefore, Schur's lemma implies, for each $s \in C$, $\rho_s=\lambda_s \iota$, where $\iota$ is the identity map and $\lambda_s$ is a scaler. Hence, $\chi(s)=n\lambda_s$ for each $s\in C$.

Now, if $G$ is finite then $\lambda^m=1$ for some $m$ and so $|\lambda|=1$, and the result is followed. However, I cannot prove $|\chi(s)|=n$ when $G$ is not finite. Is there any way to prove this or does Serre just consider the group to be finite? I am asking this because Question 3.1 of this book considers infinite groups as well.

Comment: You do not need that $|G|$ is finite to deduce that $\rho(s)$ is a scalar matrix, for any finite-dimensional representation. This can be proved directly. Choose an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $\rho(s)$, and note that the $\lambda$-eigenspace is a $G$-invariant subspace. Then it must be all of the space as $G$ acts irreducibly, so $\rho(s)$ is a scalar matrix.

Comment: I know. The paragraph in which I mentioned finiteness is after the paragraph in which I used Schur's lemma.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your question. Of course you need something like that all elements of $G$ have finite order. Otherwise take $G=\mathbb{C}^\times$.